# Need of the printer_lock when the print is inside an outer lock

Tags: python, multithreading

I was viewing the talk given by Reymond Hettinger on concurrency in Python (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zinZmE3Ogk) and i came across one of his code snippets which demonstrates the use of locks in Python . Below is the sample code of the same :

```
import threading
from threading import Thread

counter = 0

counter_lock = threading.Lock()
printer_lock = threading.Lock()

def worker():
    global counter
    with counter_lock:
        counter += 1
        with printer_lock:
            print(f"The count is {counter}")
            print("----------------")

with printer_lock:
    print("Starting up ...")


worker_threads = []
for i in range(10):
    t = Thread(target=worker)
    worker_threads.append(t)
    t.start()
for t in worker_threads:
    t.join()
```

My question is with this code block :

```
 with printer_lock:
            print(f"The count is {counter}")
            print("----------------")
```

Why do we need a printer lock when only one thread is executing these lines( due to the outer counter_lock) at any one time ?

Can anyone throw some more light on this please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without the `printer_lock` the output could get jumbled as various threads try to print something at the same time. Try taking it out and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example, I believe that it WONT make a difference if you remove the printer lock. Thats because the only printing each thread is doing is printing the counter. However, if your thread was was doing some other stuff, outside the counter_lock, then you would want to take the printer_lock each time you are printing, to prevent the output from multiple threads getting interleaved.